# How to copy text from source to destination textbox in c# windows form?

Tags: c#, .net

Give a form with controls: - A Button named btnCopy

- A Text Box named `txtSource`
- A Text Box named `txtDestination`

Write C# code segment to subscribe the Click event of the button named `btnCopy` to handle a task to copy a text from a textbox named `txtSource` to the textbox named `txtDestination`.

Comment: It is better to write the code yourself, if you have a problem, ask questions...

Comment: Within the button click event write txtDestination.Text = txtSource.Text;

Comment: Thank you everyone. now I solved.
btnCopy.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    Clipboard.SetText(txtSource.Text);
    txtDestination.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
};

Comment: Adding data to the system clipboard is unnecessary for copying text between text boxes. @USER2022

Answer (score 0):

Just double click the button in your form and set the `Text` property from your second textbox to the Text Property of the first one.